# How do i call two different highcharts on ion-toggle?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to show two different charts on `ion-toggle`, whereas I can show two different texts on ion-toggle but I can't able to show two different `highcharts` on `ion-toggle`?

```
<ion-grid>
    <h3 class="branch-income">{{ isOnline ? 'Least' : 'Top' }} 5 Branches Income

        <ion-toggle (ionChange)="updateDriverOnlineStatus($event)"  [checked]="isOnline" class="switch-btn"></ion-toggle>

    <h1 *ngIf="isOnline">
    <div class="chart-holder">
        <div id="container99"></div>
    </div>
     </h1>
    <h1 *ngIf="isOnline==false">     
        <div class="chart-holder">
            <div id="container88"></div>
        </div>
    </h1>
    </h3>


</ion-grid>
```

Comment: where is your highchart in html?

Comment: i added now, though its showing highcharts error #13.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `[(ngModel)]="isOnline"` to your toggle element, it will get the value of that toggle and you can add to your logic accordingly. Thanks

```
<ion-grid>
   <h3 class="branch-income">
      {{ isOnline ? 'Least' : 'Top' }} 5 Branches Income
      <ion-toggle (ionChange)="updateDriverOnlineStatus($event)" 
      [(ngModel)]="isOnline" [checked]="isOnline" class="switch-btn"></ion-toggle>
      <h1 *ngIf="isOnline">test1</h1>
      <h1 *ngIf="isOnline==false">test2</h1>
   </h3>
</ion-grid>
```

Comment: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'checked: true'. Current value: 'checked: false'. (This error showing bro)

Comment: try changing variable like this `isOnline: boolean = false;`

Comment: @stephen can you please upload your relevant code here https://stackblitz.com/fork/ionic

Answer (score 0):

In component:

```
public model = {
   toggleFlag: false
};
```

In html:

```
<div> 
  <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="model.toggleFlag"></ion-toggle>

  <div [hidden]="model.toggleFlag"> 
    <div class="chart-holder">
        <div id="container99"></div>
    </div>
  </div> 

  <div [hidden]="!model.toggleFlag"> 
    <div class="chart-holder">
        <div id="container99"></div>
    </div>
  </div> 

</div>
```

Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-vzaeic?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.html)

Use hidden property which show and hide from view but chart will be there but hidden.

Comment: it will not work in code snipped because angular is setup.

Comment: The only working thing is <h1> div but i cant able to view the highchart could be pls help to get the chart on ion toggle ?

Comment: i think your problem is something else also. answer is for toggle which working. check demo.

Comment: I'm getting the charts loaded at the same time whereas ion-toggle works for <h1> div but chart doesn't work on ion-toggle both the charts are already loaded . any help ??

Comment: load first chart and load second chart user enable toggle